# Replicating multiple unrelated servers

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, mariadb, master-slave-replication

We have a bunch of live websites running simple LAMP stacks. We have nightly backups to the cloud, but this means that an event like the [Strasbourg fire at OVH](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-france-ovh-fire-idUSKBN2B20NU) might happen just before your backup routine runs, leaving you with a day-long stale data.

We started investigating running MariaDB master-slave replication as a backup solution. The slave is a virtual machine in our company network, we opened the firewall of the production server for our company IP address and it works very well. This was done for one of our websites for now. Since we have different websites on different servers, we want to back them all up.

Our initial idea was to have a replicant server that could replicate all our database servers, but I didn't find any documentation or information on how to achieve that. A slave is only supposed to replicate the same data from one or more master?

The other, maybe simpler solution, is to set up machine for each server, each running a different MariaDB instance. Is this the only solution?

Comment: check out multi-source replication: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/multi-source-replication/

Comment: Thank you, what tripped me up is that I initially created an unnamed default connection, and I didn't see how to add other ones. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-replication/